# Использование сторонних зависимостей в проекте

Tags: golang

Цель: заюзать веб-сокеты под go. В большинстве примеров, найденных в сети используется библиотека Gorilla, подключается следующим образом:

```
import "github.com/gorilla/websocket"
```

Если я правильно понял, то чтобы использовать данный пакет (`github.com/gorilla/websocket`) локально, его необходимо заранее получить:

```
go get "github.com/gorilla/websocket"
```

Собственно, вопрос: после выполнения вышеупомянутой команды в директории нашего проекта на Go появляется два каталога, в одном из которых лежит бинарник, в другом - куча сырцов; являются ли все выкачанные сырцы необходимыми? *Существует ли какой-то более универсальный ("правильный") способ использования сторонних пакетов в своих проектах?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из вашего вопроса я предполагаю, что у вас GOPATH установлен в корень проекта. *Эта практика не рекомендуется.* Рекомендуется *один GOPATH на все проекты.* Прежде всего потому что это позволяет вам контролировать, какой код попадёт в проект, а какой - нет, плюс делает ваш проект совместимым с `go get`.

Что же касается сохранения зависимостей, самая надёжная и часто используемая тактика - т.н. "вендоринг". То есть, сохранение зависимостей в папку `/vendor` в корне проекта. Сделать это можно например с помощью https://github.com/tools/godep:

```
godep save ./...
```

Comment: Да, Вы абсолютно правы насчет GOPATH. Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: у себя на проекте использую https://github.com/govend/govend для контроля над зависимостями.